# QPainter: Paint device returned engine 0

Tags: qt, qgraphicstextitem

My program produces runtime warnings when I type text into `QGraphicsItem`s. The items are created like this:

```
QGraphicsTextItem* item = new QGraphicsTextItem(this)
item ->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
item ->setCacheMode(ItemCoordinateCache);
```

As soon as I start typing, the following warning is displayed:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine 0, type: 2
```

This also results in more warnings like the following, all stating that the painter is not active:

```
QPainter::translate: Painter not active 
QPainter::setClipRegion: Painter not active 
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints 
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active 
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

If I however set the cache mode to `NoCache`, everything is alright.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the context in which your code lies? Is it the first thing in main, or have you setup a QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene?

Comment: i set up QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene, and added into QGraphicsScene some custom graphic items Inherited from QGraphicsObject and all of this works fine with caching and without.

Comment: item is child custom graphic object

Comment: Please provide a smaller example that compiles.

Comment: if add item into scene directly and type in text item single line all ok, if 2 and more lines then error

Comment: auto item = new QGraphicsTextItem();
    auto font = QFont();
    font.setFamily("Arial");
    font.setPointSize(17);
    font.setStyle(QFont::StyleNormal);

    item->setFont(font);
    item->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
    item->setPlainText("text");
    item->setCacheMode(QGraphicsItem::ItemCoordinateCache);
    mScene->addItem(item);

Comment: http://s020.radikal.ru/i716/1403/b8/608d5ee1bacb.png

Comment: http://s020.radikal.ru/i723/1403/b2/b47c0f286f1d.png
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2

Comment: if item lost focus all artefacts redrawn correctly